# cloudKit and Mac OS X unable to run app with no errors (EXC_CRASH)

Tags: xcode, macos, cloudkit

I working on mac version of app my app using cloudkit. The iOS version works fine but when tried to export the app for distribution (testing) I got this error:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

kernel messages:

VM Regions Near 0x7fff786870a8 (cr2):
    __LINKEDIT             00007fff68a32000-00007fff68a46000 [   80K] r--/rwx SM=COW  /usr/lib/dyld
--> Submap                 00007fff70000000-00007fff80000000 [256.0M] r--/rwx SM=PRV  process-only VM submap
    unused shlib __DATA    00007fff76c7d000-00007fff7920c000 [ 37.6M] rw-/rw- SM=COW  system shared lib __DATA not used by this process
```

When I disable the app  Sandbox and iCloud entitlements I don't get that error but I get this error:

```
Crashed Thread:        4  Dispatch queue: NSOperationQueue 0x600000227760 :: NSOperation 0x6080000948c0 (QOS: USER_INITIATED)

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000

Application Specific Information:
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Failed to establish valid container/bundleID information'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I'm kind lost of what can be wrong with the app. If I ran the app from xcode it works just fine.

UPDATE:

If I do the following:

Archive -> Export... -> Export as Mac Application

Works but is pointing to cloudkit sandbox environment.

If I try to:

Archive ->Export .. -> Save for mac app store deployment I still get the same error:

```
Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (Code Signature Invalid)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
```

I have configure xcode with all the provision profiles (development,distribution)

[image]

The following are the code signing configuration in xcode:

[image]

But if I Archice ->Validate for the mac app store the result is "validation successful" but if I submit to the mac app store I get this warning signs next to the build number:

[image]

I'll really appreciate your help to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Without sandbox and CloudKit entitlement, this could not work. This feature is bound to the sandbox and Mac Appstore Apps only.

And with this active, you can only create an app for Mac Appstore Deployment with a valid certificate and all testing devices in the provisioning profile (as known from iOS).

I found out, there are two ways for getting the correct signed test binary:

1. Archive -> Export... -> Export as Mac Application
2. <strike>Archive -> Export... -> Save for Mac App Store Deployment</strike>

You can't build a Installer Package nor a Developer ID-signed Application with this features.

UPDATE: removed second option, seems not to work correctly

Comment: I have update my original post. Please let me know if you have any idea how to fix this

Comment: What do you mean with "is pointing to cloudkit sandbox environment."? I have an Mac Sandboxed App for the Store working with Cloudkit, and exporting it as Mac Application, the App works flawless on all Macs included in the provisioning profile. Also all Sandbox and Cloudkit Operations.

Comment: What I meant was I can only use the cloudkit sandbox environment and I need to have access to the cloudkit production environment with the mac app.

Comment: You simply can't use Cloudkit outside the Appstore!

Comment: Make a Beta build as said above to test with not productive Cloudkit. But the release version won't work until published over the appstore.

Comment: Starting with 10.12 Sierra, CloudKit now also works outside of the (Mac) App Store.